# ıs there any way delete multiple specific objects in object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example,

```
deleteIdList = [1, 2, 5];
objectList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Volvo"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Mercedes"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Renault"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "BMW"
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Skoda"
    },
];
```

Can i delete deleteIdList items with javascript array functions like filter or map?

Comment: yes, you can. what result do you want? a new array or the same array?

Comment: use `includes` and `filter`.

Comment: You can use this: `const result = objectList.filter((i) => !deleteIdList.includes(i.id));` [Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/yLVmGXx?editors=0012)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const deleteIdList = [1, 2, 5];
const objectList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Volvo" },
  { id: 2, name: "Mercedes" }, 
  { id: 3, name: "Renault" },
  { id: 4, name: "BMW" },
  { id: 5, name: "Skoda" }
];

const result = objectList.filter(o => !deleteIdList.includes(o.id));

console.log(result);
// [ 
//  { id: 3, name: "Renault" },
//  { id: 4, name: "BMW" }
// ]
```